# PHP no Browser Escrever , Ler e Atualizar .txt , Localmente

Tags: php, javascript, html5, http

No Browser do cliente ! Localmente...

Como posso criar e salvar em um arquivo .txt local na maquina do cliente o valor de duas variáveis String .

Esse script fica no login e sempre que o login for feito esse arquivo se atualiza "sobrescreve-se" localmente na maquina do cliente passando valores atualizados dessas variáveis.

E depois em outro ponto do script, ler o que esta nesse arquivo .txt "o valor das duas variáveis inseridas e atualizadas anteriormente" e comparar cada um desses valores com outras duas variáveis do meu script.

Como posso realizar esse processo ?

```
.TXT

$strGuarda01
$strGuarda02

$strCompara01 == $strGuarda01
$strCompara02 == $strGuarda02
```

Comment: Não pode. A sua afirmação "meu PHP roda no browser do cliente" está errada. O PHP é uma linguagem *server-side* e é executada apenas no servidor. O que chega para o cliente nada mais é que a resposta HTTP criada pelo PHP em conjunto com o servidor web. Ou seja, você não conseguirá manipular arquivos do lado do cliente com PHP e isso nem faz muito sentido. O que exatamente você quer fazer?

Comment: pode ser usando outro tipo de metódo eu pensei nessa forma, porem sei que ele roda no servidor porem preciso guardar e comparar valores localmente na maquina do cliente

Comment: E por quê precisa ser em arquivo? O que são essas informações? O que pretende fazer com elas? Que tipo de verificação será? Armazenar em *cookies* não seria suficiente?

Comment: ------> * Tenho um sistema de login que recebe dados de um webservice, porem ao usuario acessar o login estando ele sem estar conectado a internet, não é possível acessar o webservice em questão, por esse motivo pretendo guardar em um arquivo externo por ex. no registro do windows dessa mesma maquina onde o sistema de login esta instalado PHP, guardar o valor de 2 variáveis uma é o numero de serial do sistema que libera a entrada ao sistema através do login e outra é um numero que pode variar de 0-99 .......... continuo no prox. comentário ...

Comment: que é um numero de segurança que disponibilizo para o caso do usuário ficar sem internet por um tempo o sistema ir descontando dessa cota disponibilizada para acessos off e ir decrescendo esse numero no registro até chegar um ponto em que ele não tem saída pois acabaram-se as cotas de execuções em off e ele tem obrigatoriamente que fazer o login conectado para que o sistema atualize os dados salvos no registro do windows

Comment: Preciso da Rotina Completa php , Eu não tenho o .reg ele precisa ser criado via rotina php e escrito/guardado nele o valor de 2 variaveis e depois em outra rotina buscar ele e comparar os valores guardados nele com as ontras 2 variaveis locais para ver se são valores iguais................... Será rodado no cliente / Dados String Textos / Acredito que no Registro do Windows é mais seguro pois não se perde e fica bem guardado / no caso Pode ser um Txt sim

Comment: @Anderson Carlos Woss  Deu para compreender ?

Comment: você teria que criar uma **aplicação no cliente** (que fará as modificações no arquivo/pasta ) que se comunica com sua **aplicação web**. vejo como a melhor forma de se resolver seu problema

Comment: @teliz  Talvez ..... "socket" requisitando o seu serviço de X em X tempo, Outra solução será utilizar cookies ou o proprio LocalStorage do browser em javascript  ///// Sua ideia é boa porem nem as que citei e nem a que vc citou sei fazer e/ou criar !

Comment: Mas pelo que sei você não consegue alterar um arquivo usando script no browser.

Talvez você usando o **Eletron** [link](https://tableless.com.br/introducao-ao-electron/) possa fazer essa aplicação desktop rapidamente, apos isso crie a API para ele se comunicar com o seu servidor.(desculpe se estiver sendo redundante)

Comment: @teliz OK, porem como fazer ,,,,,   eu não sei nunca fiz nada do tipo nem parecido !  pode me ajudar  a criar e por para funcionar  ?

Comment: Estou um pouco corrido mas consigo te ajudar sim :)

Comment: @teliz Eu Agradeço,  como podemos interagir nessa ajuda  ?  por aqui mesmo ?  ou no chat ?  ou de outra forma ,  Skype etc....

Comment: Não pode guardar essas informações com JavaScript? com o localStorage?

Comment: @usuario | Pode ser de qualquer forma desde que funcione e me ajudem a criar e por para funcionar  !  Grato.

Comment: Você utiliza ajax em seu login ou faz direto no php?

Comment: @usuario  |  Direto no php !

Comment: @teliz como esta sua foto,  ou como te identificar no skype apareceu um monte .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vou tentar explicar meio por cima. Espero que entenda:

Para Salvar os dados:

```
<script>
    localStorage.setItem('strGuarda01', '<?php echo $strGuarda01;?>');  
    localStorage.setItem('strGuarda02', '$strGuarda02');
</script>
```

Para poder recuperar esses dados você pode enviar ele para o php da seguinte maneira:

```
<script>
    var strGuarda01 = localStorage.getItem('strGuarda01'), strGuarda02= localStorage.getItem('strGuarda02');
    $.POST('login.php', {'strGuarda01':strGuarda01,'strGuarda02':strGuarda02}, function(data){
      ...
    }
</script>
```

E recupera na página .php:

```
<?php
    $strGuarda01 = $_POST['strGuarda01'];
    $strGuarda01= $_POST['strGuarda02'];
    ...
?>
```

E para atualizar:

```
<script>
    localStorage.clear();
    localStorage.setItem('strGuarda01', '<?php echo $strGuarda01;?>');  
    localStorage.setItem('strGuarda02', '$strGuarda02');
</script>
```

**localStorage**

O localStorage salva dados no computador do visitante, que ficam vinculados ao (e apenas acessíveis pelo) seu domínio.

Esse tutorial talvez pode lhe ajudar: https://zenorocha.com/html5-local-storage/

Comment: |  Se compreendi localStorage é um caminho absoluto e não é alterável ,  ou seja não é algo que eu diga --- ex.  minhas variáveis vão ficar salvas no caminho c:/tal/tal/arquivo.txt   né  ?   |   esses dados dessas variáveis se perdem ao fechar o navegador ? ou ao usuário cliente fazer uma limpeza de disco ou limpar o histórico ?

Comment: O localStorage não perde ao usuário fechar o navegador nem desligar o PC. Mas eles são apagados se o usuário limpar os cache e dados de aplicativos hospedados no navegador.

Comment: Creio que não seja possível você salvar um arquivo .txt como nosso amigo **teliz** falou em outra resposta. A unica maneira de você fazer o que deseja será salvando em localStorage.

Comment: | Então se o usuário limpar o histórico ,  se perde tudo !  isso é problema.

Comment: O código vai ficar em um servidor? ou na maquina do usuário localmente?

Comment: Pode existir os dois casos,  onde eu instalo um servidor local na maquina do cliente para rodar localmente ,  e outro caso onde o usuario possui servidor web e pede para eu hospedar lá no servidor dele !

Comment: Se o código estiver em um servidor local na maquina do cliente você consegue salvar um arquivo txt dentro desse servidor. agora se estiver em um servidor web somente com sessionStorage.

Comment: Por que uma linha assim;  
    localStorage.setItem('strGuarda01', '<?php echo $strGuarda01;?>'); 
e outra assim ? 
    localStorage.setItem('strGuarda02', '$strGuarda02');

Para que esses scripts sejam executados automaticamente basta inseri-los da forma que mencionou direto no corpo do script ?

Comment: | prefiro ter um cod. script que funcione em ambas as situações !  mais seguro.

Comment: dois códigos cada um salvando uma variável as que você mencionou em sua resposta. Ou pode salvar as duas variáveis em somente um se preferir e sim você insere no corpo do arquivo

Comment: localStorage.setItem('$valor a ser guardado', '$minha variavel com o valor');

Comment: ,  E... Para que esses scripts sejam executados automaticamente basta inseri-los da forma que mencionou direto no corpo do script ?

Comment: Sim. Isso mesmo.

Comment: o entendimento das propriedades é assim ?  localStorage.setItem('$valor a ser guardado', '$minha variavel com o valor');

Comment: localStorage.setItem('um-nome-qualquer', 'valor da variavel'); EX: `localStorage.setItem('email', '<?php echo $email; ?>');`  => `localStorage.setItem('email', 'teste@gmail.com');`

Comment: Entendi  ,  só ainda não entendi por duas linhas uma para indicar e outra para instanciar ?

Comment: De uma olhada nesse link: http://blog.thiagobelem.net/armazenando-informacoes-no-computador-do-visitante-com-localstorage-e-sessionstorage

Comment: OK , Entendi !  Obrigado......  Acho que consigo avançar aqui .  Qualquer duvida chamo aqui !    Obrigado.

Answer (score 4):

Creio que **não seja possível** , pois seu código PHP está em um servidor fora do diretório onde quer fazer as modificações do arquivo, sendo assim o browser não pode fazer a alteração.